# I would like to know what's wrong with this tiny code that it doesn't provide the expected results

Tags: c, string, pointers, argv, argc

In short, the purpose behind this program is to loop through the given array of strings and print it out as is after changing any Comma (,) to Colon(:).

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
  int i;
  int j;
  int n;
  int x;
  int count = 0;

    for ( i = 1, n = argc -1; i <= n; i++)
  {
    for ( j = 0, x = strlen(argv[i]); j < x; j++)
    {

      if(strcmp(&argv[i][j], ",") == 0)
      {
        //count++;
        printf(":");
      }

      else {printf("%c", argv[i][j]);}
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
  //printf("Count = %i & i = %i & j= %i\n", count, i, j);
  //printf("x= %i\n",x);
}
```

Here is the result that I get after running the code:

```
$ ./conversion 12, 1,2 ,12
12:1,2,12
```

What I expect is to get this instead:

```
$ ./conversion 12, 1,2 ,12
12:1:2:12
```

Conclusion:
I believe that for some reason the comma is not recognized in the beginning/middle of the string
It works if it is at the end of the text though. I hope you can tell me how to obtain the expected result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you're printing one character at a time to `stdout` use `putchar()` instead of `printf()` to reduce overheads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `&argv[i][j]` is the i-th string from the j-th character on. When you compare that to the comma string, `","` it will match only when the comma is at the end of the string. In your example, the comma is found in `"12,"`, but not in `"1,2"` or `",12"`.

When you print the characters, you use the expression `argv[i][j]` without the `&`, which is the j-th character of the i-th string. Use that when you check for a comma, too:

```
if (argv[i][j] == ',') // comma found!
```

Of course, you must check against a character literal in single quotes here. `strcmp` is useful for comparing null-terminated strings. Individual characters can be compared with normal comparsison operators.